# how can I make TV webapp using springboot with tizen?

Tags: java, web-applications, tizen, television

I want to make a samsung smart tv app with tizen.
I've made an webpage using springboot.

I tried making the app using that webpage codes I made, but I've got to know Tizen doesn't support java but html, css,and javascript only.

So I used meta http-equip="refresh", and let index.html go to my webpage url,
but there were long loading time, and ugly ui for a waiting page..
also remote control's pointer was weird. (not focusing on a certain button, but there is a cursor)

is there no way to solve this problem?
I've tried to find a way but I couldn't. please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are making a redirect to your website (hosted in internet).

Maybe would be better starting reading the basic concepts about Samsung Smart TV apps [here](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop)

If you try to open external content (hosted websites) into your app the TV will use its web browser to open it.